# Run a python function until has no exception at all

Tags: python, exception

A generic question - 
Suppose I have a function that can throw any kind of exception sometimes, and sometimes not. As a simple example draw randomly 2 numbers and divide them (the second one could be 0).
I want to run it until there are no exceptions at all, is that possible?

Comment: Please add any code you have tried, without some effort on your part to answer your question, this will probably be closed. At least, can you add the code you are trying to run, and the exceptions you are seeing?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Tony I added an example

Comment: @Codevan - in the example you gave, and I realise it's only an example, it would be better to check the divisor is not zero, rather than waiting for an exception to be thrown. My point is there are usually other ways to handle the situation, other than using exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    try:
        callFunction()
        break
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

keep calling the function until it doesn't make an error:

```
done = False
while not done:
    try:
        #call your function here
    except:
        done = False
    else:
        done = True
```